# How to execute batch file before debugging with VS Code

Tags: typescript, debugging, npm, visual-studio-code

I'm developing with Typescript, nodeJS and VS Code.

Debugging with VS Code, I have configuration in my `launch.json`.

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch via NPM",
        "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "run-script",
            "debug"
        ],
        "port": 9229
},
```

Is it possible to run a batch file before the service is started? With console I would normally run it with

```
env.cmd
npm start
```

Answer (score 6):

You should create a **new task** that you want to execute before debug with a specified "identifier" and it as a "preLaunchTask" into your launch.json (the task type can be also a "shell type" that will be executed as a shell command)

e.g.: my build:test task in launch.json:

```
 {
    "type": "npm",
    "script": "build:test",
    "identifier": "buildtest",
    "group": {
        "kind": "test",
        "isDefault": true
    }
}
```

and the related debug task:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Mocha Tests",
    "preLaunchTask": "buildtest",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
    "args": [
        "-u",
        "tdd",
        "--timeout",
        "999999",
        "--colors",
        "${workspaceFolder}/temp/test/index.js"
    ],
    "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
}
```