# debug with VS CODE

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

the scenario is as follows:
 i want debug a project with VS CODE, normally the project is started by a batch file, and then run some javascript code. now, i want to debug the javascript code, but i have no idea about how to do that, please give me some instruction if some know something.

i have searched some questions concerning the similar problem, but there is no specific answer, just like the link below says:
[How to execute batch file before debugging with VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193079/how-to-execute-batch-file-before-debugging-with-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

Change your batch script to pass the `--inspect` parameter to node, then add an attach config like this:

```
{
    "name": "Attach to Process",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "attach",
    "port": 9229
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_attaching-to-nodejs

Comment: really thanks for your instant response. and i have visited the link you gave it out. However, i am still confused about "Change your batch script to pass the --inspect parameter to node", what is the meaning of this sentence. please give me more specific instructions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Change `node program.js` to `node --inspect=9229 program.js`